# Открытие предыдущего аккордеона при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap

Есть аккордеон -

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.prevent-step').on('click', function() {
    var preventCard = $(this).closest('.card').prev();
    console.log(preventCard.children('button'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />



<div class="accordion" id="insurance-steps">



  <div class="card one">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link step" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                Шаг 1
              </button>
      </h5>
    </div>

    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#insurance-steps">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link second-step" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                  Шаг 2
                </button>
      </h5>
    </div>

    <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#insurance-steps">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
        on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. 
        <button class="prevent-step">Предыдущий шаг</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Нашел родительский соседний элемент.
Заступорился на том, как теперь выбрать дочерний элемент (кнопку по которой аккордеон откроется) и повесить click на неё.
Суть - при нажатии на кнопку, свернуть текущий аккордеон и открыть предыдущий.
Если есть реализация легче чем эта - буду рад помощи ;)

p.s. хочу добавить инпуты в аккордеон
p.s.s. они не будут ресетиться при скрытии его ?

Answer (score 0):

Решил все свои трудности атрибутами bootstrap

```
<button class="prevent-step" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">Предыдущий шаг</button>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />



<div class="accordion" id="insurance-steps">



  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link step" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                Шаг 1
              </button>
      </h5>
    </div>

    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#insurance-steps">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
        on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
        raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>




  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link second-step" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                Шаг 2
              </button>
      </h5>
    </div>

    <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#insurance-steps">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
        on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
        raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
        <button class="prevent-step" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">Предыдущий шаг</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>





  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingThree">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link second-step" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseThree">
                Шаг 3
              </button>
      </h5>
    </div>

    <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-parent="#insurance-steps">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
        on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
        raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
        <button class="prevent-step" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseTwo">Предыдущий шаг</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```